# Is it how to set up an ObjectMapper dynamically at the time of user session creation?

Tags: java, spring, rest, jackson

Currently in my project, the ObjectMapper is set to the spring XML, but I would like some settings in this ObjectMapper to be different, depending on the logged-in user. It is possible?

Comment: Just write a wrapper function that returns the desired mapper depending on a variable user object and call it in code wherever you need it.

Comment: Instead of calling when I need it, I'd like to set it as the default for that session, so it does not impact both existing code and future implementations.